# how to create a statically linked golang executable with go 1.5+

Tags: go, rkt

golang version < 1.5 - there are plenty of static linking examples, posts and recipes.  What about >= 1.5? (google search has returned no useful results for my search terms.) Anyone have any recommendations on how to produce a statically linked binary that can be executed inside a basic rkt (from CoreOS) container?

my go:

```
$go version
go version go1.5 linux/amd64
```

when I try to run my container:

```
sudo rkt --insecure-skip-verify run /tmp/FastBonusReport.aci
```

I get:

```
[38049.477658] FastBonusReport[4]: Error: Unable to open "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2": No such file or directory
```

suggesting that the executable in the container is depending on this lib and hence not static.

my manifest looks like:

```
cat <<EOF > /tmp/${myapp}/manifest
{
    "acKind": "ImageManifest",
    "acVersion": "0.9.0",
    "name": "${lowermyapp}",
    "labels": [
        {"name": "os", "value": "linux"},
        {"name": "arch", "value": "amd64"}
    ],
    "app": {
        "exec": [
            "/bin/${myapp}"
        ],
        "user": "0",
        "group": "0"
    }
}
EOF
```

my command line to build the binary looks like:

```
go build ${myapp}.go
```

This [article](http://blog.hashbangbash.com/2014/04/linking-golang-statically/) has a few examples golang < 1.5. And then there is this [getting started](https://coreos.com/rkt/docs/latest/getting-started-guide.html) article on the CoreOS site.

Comment: Can you show us how you're building your app? The process hasn't really changed.

Comment: and I added some links to articles.

Comment: have you set `CGO_ENABLED=0`?

Comment: Not required but could you possibly provide some context and/or links to information about `rkt`? Yours is the first use of the tag and I at least am not familiar with it.

Comment: JimB's comment seems right. 1.5 doesn't dynamically link Go code by default, so your problem is probably with Go linking to the system's C library for DNS reoslution, which was also what older versions did. `CGO_ENABLED=0` turns that off.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: rkt: https://github.com/coreos/rkt

Comment: While I still like to create static binaries from my go projects I have also started using rkt-builder to build my projects inside a rkt container. This has a number of cool side effects.

Answer (score 11):

I hate to answer my own question. The comments have been correct `CGO_ENABLED=0 go build ./...` seems to have have done the trick.

While it was not part of the original question, once the program started executing in the rkt container it could not perform a proper DNS request. So there must be something else going on too.

Comment: Is this running on Mac OS X (darwin)? I thought this was the only platform where DNS lookups are not done by Go itself.

Comment: @Volker: dns lookups are done in go when nsswitch.conf permits, but the cgo resolver is still linked so it can be used when needed (there's also a ` GODEBUG=netdns=` option for switching back and forth at runtime, which needs both available)

Comment: @Richard you have to add your own /etc/hosts to your container, like they do [here](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/scripts/build-aci#L64), in the etcd project.

Answer (score 10):

Static linking:

Go 1.5:

```
go build -ldflags "-extldflags -static" ...
```

With Go 1.6 I had to use:

```
go build -ldflags "-linkmode external -extldflags -static" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

try to build static link version :

```
go build -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -tags netgo,osusergo .
```

use `-tags osusergo,netgo` to force static build without glibc dependency library.