# Is it possible to build a static sqlite Go app by docker golang:alpine image?

Tags: sqlite, docker, go

I'm trying to build my app which contains go-sqlite3 by docker.

main.go

```
package main

import (
        "database/sql"

        _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
        sql.Open("sqlite3", "test.db")
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN apk add --no-cache sqlite-libs sqlite-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache build-base
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY *.go ./
RUN go-wrapper download
RUN go-wrapper install
```

I use this command to copy the compiled program out to my host OS (Arch Linux).

```
docker build -t mygo .
docker run --rm -v $$PWD:/usr/src/app mygo /bin/cp /go/bin/app /usr/src/app
```

The problem is the compiled program is missing dynamic library

```
$  ldd app
   ...
   libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => not found
```

What I expected is like

```
$  ldd app
not a dynamic executable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer to [how to create a statically linked golang executable with go 1.5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113190/how-to-create-a-statically-linked-golang-executable-with-go-1-5)

Change the Dockerfile's `go-wrapper install` line into

```
RUN go-wrapper install -ldflags "-linkmode external -extldflags -static"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your problem it depends on how you build the Golang executable.

You should build your package with `CGO_ENABLED` set to `0`. In order to do that, before compiling, simply run `export CGO_ENABLED=0` on your terminal than build your Golang binary.

If you are interested you can find more info about `CGO` [here](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)

Comment: How would you be able to use the C library for sqlite if disabling CGO?